# Watir incompatible character encodings

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, utf-8, watir

I am writing this bot with ruby and ran into trouble, that showed up to be more complicated, than i would ever thought it could be. I read many similar articles, but nothing really helped.

It might have nothing to do with watir, but just to be specific i say it is. Also, i am on Fedora. this is what i tried:

```
table = browser.table(:index , 7)
puts table[1][1].text
```

the html table fragment is something like:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   something...
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td/>
  <td>
   Likiškėlių 
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

i get

```
    /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/vendor/okjson.rb:364:in `[]=': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/vendor/okjson.rb:364:in `unquote'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/vendor/okjson.rb:288:in `strtok'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/vendor/okjson.rb:254:in `tok'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/vendor/okjson.rb:217:in `lex'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/vendor/okjson.rb:45:in `decode'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/adapters/ok_json.rb:13:in `load'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/multi_json-1.7.2/lib/multi_json.rb:120:in `load'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/json_helper.rb:11:in `json_load'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:619:in `raw_execute'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:597:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:508:in `getElementText'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:108:in `text'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:86:in `text'
    from watir.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

i also tried :

```
 .gsub!(/\P{ASCII}/, '')
 .delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}")
```

variations, but it did't worked out. Please help! Why is encoding so complicated? I am clueless.

**Edit:** actually, if it helps, i dont need to print the string, but only to write it to file, but the errors are the same.

and my ruby version is : ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i386-linux]

**Edit:** I also tried:

```
# encoding: ASCII-8BIT
or 
# encoding: utf-8
with 
puts table[1][1].text.length
```

yet still the same errors

**Edit** because it wouldn't even show .bytesize , i bet it's watir. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got something. [I changed my watir browser from firefox to chrome.](http://watirmelon.com/2011/07/08/using-the-super-duper-chromedriver-with-watir-webdriver/) And now i get the encoded string and no errors. Viola!

Answer (score 0):

Installing the "json" or "oj" gems will fix this problem.

See https://github.com/intridea/multi_json for the full list of supported JSON engines.